# Split a movie so that each GIF is under a certain file size

Tags: ffmpeg, gif, avconv

**Problem**

I want to convert a long movie into a series on animated GIFs.

Each GIF needs to be <5MB.

Is there any way to determine how large a GIF will be *while it is being encoded?*

**Progress So Far**

I can split the movie into individual frames:

`ffmpeg -i movie.ogv -r 25 frameTemp.%05d.gif`

I can then use `convert` from ImageMagick to create GIFs.  However, I can't find a way to determine the likely file size *before* running the command.

Alternatively, I can split the movie into chunks:

`ffmpeg -i movie.ogv -vcodec copy -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:20:00 output1.ogv`

But I've no way of knowing if, when I `convert` the file to a GIF it will be under 5MB.

A 10 second scene with a lot of action may be over 5MB (bad!) and a static scene could be under 5MB (not a problem, but not very efficient).

**Ideas**

I think that what I want to do is convert the entire movie into a GIF, then find a way to split it by file size.

Looking at ImageMagick, I can split a GIF into frames, but I don't see a way to split it into animated GIFs of a certain size / length.

So, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently is no "Stop at this filesize" option in `avconv` that i'm aware of. It can, of course, be hacked together quite quickly, but currently `libav` project doesn't do quick hacks, so it'll likely appear in `ffmpeg` first.

In addition to this you are facing a problem of animated gif being a very old format, and thus doing some rather strange things. Let me explain the way it normally works:

1. You create a series of frames from first to last and put them on top of one another.
2. You make all the "future" frames invisible, and set to appear at the specific time.
3. In order to make the size of the file smaller, you look "below" the new frames, and if the previous pixel is the same, you set that particular pixel as opaque.

That third step is the only time compression that is done in the animated gif, without it the file size will be much larger (since every pixel must be saved again and again).

However, if you are unsure when was the last break, you cannot determine if the pixel is the same as the previous "frames". After all, this particular frame can be the very first one in the image.

If the limit of 5MiB is soft enough to allow going a little over it, you probably can put something together that just keeps adding frame after frame, and calculating the final file size right away. As soon as one goes over the limit, just stop and use the next frame as the starting point for the next file.